# Find & replace string in multiple csv files under series of subfolders

Tags: python

###### Folder structure

```
|FolderA
|-Foldera1
|      A_a1_001.csv
|      A_a1_002.csv
|-Folderb1
|      A_b1_001.csv
|      A_b1_002.csv
```

###### CSV format

a_a1_001.csv

```
XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
123,456,789,AAA
```

a_a1_002.csv

```
XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
376,452,953,AAA
```

###### Request

Find all the csv files in the root to find&replace certain string, and save it back as the same path & filename.

###### Code

```
import OS
texttofind='AAA'
texttoreplace='BBB'
sourcepath=os.walk(r"/Users/Gens/Documents/FolderA/")
for file in sourcepath:
    inputfile=os.walk(r"/Users/Gens/Documents/FolderA/")
    with open (inputfile,'r') as inputfile:
        filedata=inputfile.read()
        freq=0
        freq=filedata.count(texttofind)
    destinationpath=os.walk(r"/Users/Gens/Documents/FolderA/")
    filedata=filedata.replace(texttofind,texttoreplace)
    with open(destinationpath,'w')as file:
        file.write(filedata)
    file.close()
```

###### Questions

It shows:

```
with open (inputfile,'r') as inputfile:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not generator
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you studied the documentation for os.walk() ?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) returns a 3-tuple

So, walk the tree finding files that end with .csv. Open in mode r+, read entire content and just do a string replace. Seek to BOF, write the (possibly) modified text then truncate.

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join

FIND = 'AAA'
REPLACE = 'BBB'
ROOT = '/Users/Gens/Documents/FolderA/'

for dirpath, _, filenames in walk(ROOT):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            with open(join(dirpath, filename), 'r+') as csv: # note the open mode
                text = csv.read().replace(FIND, REPLACE)
                # seek to BOF
                csv.seek(0)
                csv.write(text)
                # truncate is necessary in case the output is smaller than the original input
                csv.truncate()
```